# Problema no POST usando JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html5, api

Estou estudando JQuery e estou com um probleminha para dar `POST` em uma API que tenho.

Segue meu `html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Teste do Front End</title>    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hVVnYaiADRTO2PzUGmuLJr8BLUSjGIZsDYGmIJLv2b8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="javascript/ListarCategorias.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <div id="stage1" >
        <table id="stage2">
            <tr>
              <th id="CategoriaNome">Categorias</th>
              <th id="QtdeProdutos">Qtde Produtos</th>
              <th id="Acoes">Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <form id="cadCategoria">
      <label >Categoria</label>
      <input type="text" name="s" placeholder="Nome da Categoria" id="Nome">
      <input type="submit" value="Salvar" class="btn btn-primary" id="btn-submit">
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Segue o código em javascript

```
 //Listar usuarios
$(document).ready(function() {

    paginaGET = 'http://localhost:55119/private/obtertodas';
    paginaPOST = "http://localhost:55119/private/adicionar";

    $.ajax({  
        //type:'GET',        //Definimos o método HTTP usado
        url: paginaGET,//Definindo o arquivo onde serão buscados os dados
        dataType: 'json',   //Definimos o tipo de retorno
        cache: false,
        //se ocorrer um erro na chamada ajax, retorna este alerta
        //possiveis erros: pagina nao existe, erro de codigo na pagina, falha de comunicacao/internet, etc etc etc
        error: function() {
            alert('Erro: Alguma coisa deu errada ao retornar as Categorias... =(');
        },
        success: function(dados) {
            for(var i=0;dados.length>i;i++){  
                console.log(dados[i].CategoriaNome);
                document.getElementById('stage2').innerHTML += "<tr><td>"+dados[i].CategoriaNome+"</td><td>" + dados.length + "</td></tr>";
            }
        }
    });

    $("#btn-submit").click(function() {
        // var Categoria = new Object();
        // Categoria.CategoriaNome = $("#Nome").val();

        var Categoria = {
            CategoriaNome: $("#Nome").val()
        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: paginaPOST,
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: Categoria,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log("====== Categoria adicionada! ======");
            },
            error: function() { 
                alert("Algum erro no POST. Categoria lida: " + Categoria.CategoriaNome + " " + Categoria);
            }
        });
    });

    // $.getJSON(pagina, function(resp) {
    //     $.each(resp, function(key, value) {
    //        console.log(value.CategoriaNome);
    //        document.getElementById('stage2').innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + value.CategoriaNome + "</td><td>" + "</td></tr>";
    //     });
    // });
    });
```

Antes estava dando certo, mas não sei pq não está dando mais. Ele sempre está caindo no `error`. Sei que minha api está funcionando pq testo usando o Postman e o `POST` funciona lindamente.  Alguém pode me ajudar?

No chrome, aparece [isto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/igMm1.jpg) e no `adicionar` aparece [isto](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UYmT1.jpg). Não sei se a resposta está ali.

Comment: Um dos motivos pode ser que o correto é `method: 'POST'` ao invés de `type: "POST"`. Se isso não funcionar, veja se há alguma mensagem no console.

Comment: @LucasCosta agradeço pelo comentário, mas não funcionou. Ainda estou com o mesmo resultado.

Comment: O problema é no ajax do load ou do botão?

Comment: @Aline realmente não sei. Procurei fazer um teste neste trecho aqui`error: function() { 
                alert("Algum erro no POST. Categoria lida: " + Categoria.CategoriaNome + " " + Categoria);
            }`. Sei que ele está lendo o que eu escrevo pq aparece no `error`

Comment: Pode testar substituindo os parâmetros do ajax por: url: paginaGET,    , processData: false, contentType: false, type: 'POST' ?

Comment: @Aline tirando até o `data: Categoria` ? Ou adicionando o `processData: false` e mudando o parâmetro do `contentType` por `false`?

Comment: Se seu método está esperando obrigatoriamente um parametro com valor, vai ter que enviar. Senão remove. Remove o contentType. Só quero saber se tá chegando no método.

Comment: @Aline Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55435/discussion-between-iago-frota-and-aline).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Se seu `$("#btn-submit")` for um `input submit`, troque pra: `button`.

Comment: Obrigado Aline! O problema era isso mesmo.